# Xamarin Studio for Windows detects .Net version as 4.0

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

Xamarin studio for windows detects .net version as 4.0, whereas I'm having 4.6.

It is recommended to use 4.5 but what's bothering me is the version detected is .Net 4.0 as per log.

I've version verified through

```
c:\>reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\full" /v version

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\full
    version    REG_SZ    4.6.01586
```

Here is the log file from appdata/xamarin/logs

```
INFO [2016-10-20 10:37:24Z]: Did not find previous version from which to migrate data
INFO [2016-10-20 10:37:24Z]: Starting Xamarin Studio 6.1.1 (build 15)
INFO [2016-10-20 10:37:24Z]: Running on Microsoft .NET 4.0.30319.42000
INFO [2016-10-20 10:37:24Z]: Operating System: Windows 10.0.14393.0 (64-bit)
INFO [2016-10-20 10:37:24Z]: Found GTK# version 2.12.22
```

**Edit**

[image: Xamarin Process in task manager]

I am seeing Xamarin Process in task manager, but the foreground is nowhere to be found.

Any ideas?

PS: I have VS2015 but not happy with it's code completion/suggestion features.

Answer (score 1):

.NET version numbers and CLR ***runtime*** version numbers are NOT the same.

In your case:

```
`4.0.30319.42000` = .NET 4.6 / Windows 64-bit capable Runtime
```

CLR Runtime vs .Net Version:

```
CLR version     .NET version`
1.0             1.0
1.1             1.1
2.0             2.0, 3.0, 3.5
4               4, 4.5, 4.6
```

Ref: [.NET Framework Versions and Dependencies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049(v=vs.110).aspx)

Ref: [.NET_Framework_version_history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history)

Ref: [Common Language Runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime)

Comment: TLDR: .NET 4.6. is built on top of the CLR, which is why some features of C# which could be nice are not added, to make sure the CLR interface does not need to be changed (yet ?)